# Images scaled in safari & chrome but not in ff & opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, cross-browser

I'm using an image slider called jb gallery 3.0 - running using jQuery.

It's just a normal image slider, but it's got a feature that detects the browser size and then scales the image to the size of the browser ie. if your viewing on an iPad it will give you a smaller image so that you can still see the entire picture.

The resizing is done each time the image loads in the slider, so if you resize the window in between slides, the next time the image loads it will be scaled... No need to refresh the page.

This all works fine it safari and chrome, but in firefox and opera (12.14) it doesn't, it just serves the full size image cropped...

I've made a js fiddle of what's happening here -  http://jsfiddle.net/ktvvW/5/ - try resizing the 'result' panel in chrome or safari to see what's meant to be happening.

Any idea why this doesn't work in ff or opera?

```
.
```

Cheers

Comment: Doesn't resize in FF for me.

Comment: @isherwood, thats the problem its not working in ff

Comment: Apologies. I misread. Unfortunately my SO time is limited at the moment and I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forcing webkit behaviour on the jbgallery-3.0.js script seems to fix the issue.
See the options below, I'm forcing webkit to true (disregarding the userAgent).
I've tested this on both FF and Opera and functionality is as expected, the images display with the same zoom  as in Chrome.

```
$(".jbgallery").jbgallery({  
    style    : "zoom",       //"centered"|"zoom"|"original" - image style  
    menu     : "simple",         //false|"numbers"|"simple"|"slider" - menu type  
    shortcuts: [37, 39],         //[prev,next] - keyboard code shortcuts  
    slideshow: true,            //true|false - autostart slideshow  
    fade     : true,             //true|false - disable all fade effects  
    popup    : false,            //true|false - modal box & traditional popup hack to display multiple gallery (3.0 : fullscreen:false)  
    randomize: 0,                //0|1|2 - randomize first image (1) or randomize "slideshow" (2) - blackout: http://www.grayhats.org  
    caption  : false,             //true|false - show/disable internal caption system  
    autohide : false,            //true|false - auto hide menu & caption  
    clickable: false,            //true|false - "image click & go"  
    current  : 1,                //number     - set initial photo (modal "hack" - see demo. don't use "hash". jbgallery use "location.hash" only in popup mode)  
//    webkit   : (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search(/webkit/) != -1),  //boolean - used for specific browser hack. if you want, you can force disable this flag & try to find crossbrowser solution  
    webkit   : true,
    ie6      : (/MSIE 6/i.test(navigator.userAgent)), //boolean - IDEM  
    ie7      : (/MSIE 7/i.test(navigator.userAgent)), //boolean - IDEM  
    labels   : {                 //labels of internal menu  
        play : "play",  
        next : "next",  
        prev : "prev",  
        stop : "stop",  
        close: "close",  
        info : "info"  
    },  
    timers   : {                 //timers   
        fade    : 1000,           //fade duration  
        interval: 3000,          //slideshow interval  
        autohide: 7000           //autohide timeout  
    },  
    delays: {                    //delays (timers) to improve usability and reduce events  
        mousemove: 200,          //used by autohide. cancel autohide timeout every XXXms.   
        resize   : 10,          //used by ie6 to reduce events handled by window.resize  
        mouseover: 800           //used by tooltip. show tooltip only if the mouse STAY over thumb for XXXms  
    },  
    close    : function(){},     //callback handled by menu's button close. see demo. example : close : function(){window.close()}  
    before   : function(){},     //callback handled BEFORE image gallery loaded  
    after    : function(ev){},   //callback(ev) handled AFTER image gallery loaded. receive the native load event.  
    load     : function(ev){},   //callback(ev) handled AFTER native image load event. receive the native load event.  
    ready    : function(el){$('.jbg-menu').hide(); $('.jbg-loading').remove(); $('.jbg-caption').remove(); $('.jbg-menu-opacity').remove();},   //callback(el) handled AFTER jbgallery render. receive the HTML element.  
    fullscreen: false,            //true|false : the most important feature of jbgallery 3.0. now jbgallery can "stay in a box" and have multiple istance in one page.  
    push      : function(o){},   //callback handled by push public method (JBGALLERY API). receive the object/string/array of objects/array of strings passed from external. useful for external menu system  
    unshift   : function(o){},   //callback handled by unshift public method (JBGALLERY API). receive the object/string/array of objects/array of strings passed from external.  
    shift     : function(){},    //callback handled by shift public method   
    pop       : function(){},    //callback handled by pop public method   
    empty     : function(){}     //callback handled by empty public method   
});
```

Here's the [**link to my jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/YpCU6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the CSS which is an issue.

**original**

```
.jbgallery .jbgallery-target.zoom {
    min-height: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
}
```

**modified**

```
.jbgallery .jbgallery-target.zoom {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**error** had to add the css in the css panel as the original was in the plugin css

*here is a link of the new css* http://jsfiddle.net/ktvvW/8/

Comment: thanks, but changing the css to this stretches and distorts the proportions of the image to get it to fit into the browser window. Were as with the original in chrome and safari it uses a mixture of image scaling and cropping to constantly fill the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know how to do this:

Change the load function like below:

```
load     : function(ev){$(".zoom").css("width",$("#slider").width()),$(".zoom").css("height","auto");$(".zoom").css("left","0px");$(".zoom").css("top","auto")},
```

It will work on all browsers, tested and worked successfully

Answer (score 0):

I have not the full answer of this, but I had a similar issue in the past with this. I learnt that Gecko (Firefox) and Webkit (Safari and Chrome) do not handle images the same way. The information of the size of the image was not available when I was trying to scale it, so it was not possible to scale them with the same code.

I can only suggest to do some research on image + onload event. This would be a javascript issue in my point of view.